# Verstile data-storage: abstracting through DDD to store in either relational or document databases?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, architecture

I've been working on a small project, trying to develop a versatile data-storage option, which would allow me to use both relational and document databases. I'm starting with MySQL and MongoDB, for testing purposes. All my logic and data is stored in domain objects (comprised of Value Objects), so, i just need an elegant way of "mapping" that to the proper data-storage.

Is there any design pattern that might be able to help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go for the Domain-driven design (DDD) approach, a **Repository** might be what you are looking for.

First, you will need to define your Repository contract (or Interface), usually something like this (adjusting for whatever language you are using):

```
public IMyObjectRepository {
    MyObject get(int id);
    Collection<MyObject> getAll();
    void save(MyObject myObject); 
    void delete(int id);
}
```

And then you can have an implementation for MySQL and MongoDB.

To decouple clients from the implementation of the `IMyObjectRepository` and how it is created, clients can request it through an **Abstract Factory** Pattern, or similar. You can then return to them the correct implementation, based on a properties file, or some other sort of environment introspection.

The **DDD** aspect of this is probably secondary -- you could do this without **DDD**. Your main concern is defining your persistence contract in some sort of implementation-neutral way (an Interface), and having a way to get a reference to it without coupling clients to the implementation (the Abstract Factory). A **Respository** is one way -- you could do it in a **DAO** (or a combination of the two).

[Here is an example using **DAOs** and and **Abstract Factory**](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=128) that may give you some ideas.